# How do I pass a nil/null parameter to a stored function?

Tags: go, sqlx

The server receives a `GET` request which has the `territory_id` parameter. This parameter can be `nil` if the user does not need a filter by territory, or may have an `integer` number if the user wants to get records only for a specific territory.

Code:

```
func GetDataList (response http.ResponseWriter, request * http.Request) {
    params: = GetRequestParams (request.URL.Query ())
    normalID, _: = strconv.Atoi (params ["normal_id"])
    territoryId, _: = strconv.Atoi (params ["territory_id"])

    var listToCheck [] ObjectDataNormal
    query = `select * from get_list_for_predict (year: = $1, territory_in: = $2)`
    rows, err = db.Queryx (query,
        2011,
        territoryId)
    if rows! = nil {
            // code
    }
    // code
}

func GetRequestParams (values url.Values) map [string] string {
    urlValues: = make (map [string] string, len (values))
    for k, v: = range values   {
        urlValues   [k] = v [0]
    }
    return urlValues
}
```

The stored procedure in postgresql is designed so that if `territory_in` is `ISNULL`, then the filter for this parameter does not work, otherwise, if `territory_in` is equal to 5, for example, records are taken where the value in the territory field is 5.

And how to implement this on the server side?
If I put `territory_id = nil` in postman, I get:

> `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "nil"`

If null, then:

> `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "null".`

Also `territroyID` can not be equal `nil`. How to pass null to a function depending on user request?

In theory I can check in postages function `territory_in = 0`, instead of `IS NULL`. Since when converting a `string` to `int`(`strconv.Atoi (params ["territory_id"])`) `territory_in` it will be set to 0. But I'm wondering how to send a null parameter to a storage function in golang?

I use sqlx and pgx.

Comment: *"But I'm wondering how to send a null parameter to a storage function in golang?"* By sending `nil`, not `"nil"` and not `"null"`, but `nil`, the one from Go's [predefined identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers).

Comment: ... so what you can do, in Go, is to declare the param as `var territoryId interface{}` (this defaults to `nil` since the "zero" value of any interface is `nil`), then do the `strconv.Atoi` operation in an `if` short declaration, check the result in the condition part of the `if` and if it is greater than `0` then set `territoryId` to that result. Pass that `territoryId` to the sql executing code and you're done.

Comment: ... something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/hduw5OUBRVG

Comment: @mkopriva _"By sending nil, not "nil" and not "null", but nil"_. My question was not about what to send: `nil`, `"null"`, etc. I asked how to turn a parameter from a `GET` request into a `nil `or an `int` value. Thank you for the example with interfaces. Which approach is better , with the `interface` , or change the `postgresql` function to check for 0?

Comment: I don't know which is "better", maybe go with the one that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save `territoryId` as a `*int` instead of `int`, you can pass `nil`:

```
func strToIntPtr(s string) *int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    return &i 
}

territoryId := strToIntPtr(params["territory_id"])
```

And then `territoryId` will be `nil` anytime it's not a valid `int`.  So they can pass `nil`, `null`, or `any` (or anything that's not a number) and you just treat it as `null`.